# Best way to draw this diagram (and similar)?

Tags: drawing, graphviz, diagram, tikz

I have this game theory "tree house" diagram that is relatively complicated, shown below. I'm looking for a general, powerful tool to do stuff like this so I'll never have to ask this question again. I don't really mind the learning curve or having to code, as long as investing time into it is worthwhile. I'm hoping the tool is cross-platform and open source, but these are really just extras.

So far, I've checked out LaTeX/TikZ and Graphviz. Also, out of curiosity, what do you think the below diagram was drawn in?

Thanks for reading!

[image: tree house diagram]

Comment: I would use tikz for the overall diagram and `nicematrix` in particular for for the tables. Tikz can definitely draw all the elements from your image and you can automate a lot of the positioning relative to each other.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the `nicematrix` suggestion, it seems pretty great. Would TikZ/`nicematrix` make it easy to support those colors/fonts too?

Comment: There are basically no limitations for colours in tikz. Either use a similar colour from the predefined ones in the xcolor package or you can define your own.

Comment: Based on the edge placement (not to the edge of the node and not to the center), I guess that an interactive drawing tool was used

Comment: What does cross-platform mean?

Comment: You might also consider SVG (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/) (convertible to other output formats) and/or the pic/gpic/dpic language (I like dpic https://gitlab.com/aplevich/dpic)